# Can I use my OctopusDeploy built-in Package Repository in Manage NuGet Packages?

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy

I have a working Octopus Deploy server which has a library of packages I built. 
I have an assembly which depends on one of the assemblies which I have deployed in Octopus Deploy and which is currently in that repository. I tried adding it as a package source in NuGet Package Manager, with my repository's URL (something like:

> http://myoctoserver/app#/library

).
It will not populate the list Manage NuGet Packages of Visual Studio 2013, although the Microsoft and .NET and the nugget.org will populate.
 Documentation doesn't appear to address this at OctopusDeploy.com. Is this something that can be done, or does my organization need to make an external NuGet feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Octopus Server provides a write-only repository and it can't be consumed by other NuGet clients.

There are many options available to you depending on your budget / hardware

[ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget/overview)

[MyGet](http://www.myget.org/)

[NuGet.Lucene](https://github.com/themotleyfool/NuGet.Lucene)

[NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/wiki/Hosting-the-NuGet-Gallery-Locally-in-IIS)

Answer (score 3):

Octopus built in package repository is not mean't to be consumed by others.

The nuget packages there, are built specifically for Octopus. They have different structure. These packages are meant to be unpacked directly to a specific location, and run by either Windows service or IIS.

Also, from docs:

> It is important to understand that the Octopus server provides a
>   write-only repository; intended for hosting application packages only
>   . Packages that are pushed to the Octopus server can't be consumed by
>   other NuGet clients like Visual Studio. If you need a NuGet feed for
>   sharing libraries between your development projects, a separate NuGet
>   repository is required.

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Package+repositories

We host internal nuget server ourselves, which works very nicely.